# Trivial question about Maclaurin Series

Tags: complex-analysis

$\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{n}$  $(|z|<1)$

I don't quite understand the constrain of $|z|<1$. The function is undefined when $z=1$, but I don't see any problem in having $|z|=1$ because  if we let $z=x+yi$, $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1$, so the denominator is not equal to zero.

Comment: The series doesn't converge when $|z| \ge 1$.

Comment: If we let z=-5, then the denominator is not equal to zero. Does the series with z=-5 converge?

Comment: Fair point. It would keep growing on and on.

Comment: Even though $1/(1-z)$ makes sense if $z\ne 1,$ the series doesn't make sense if $|z| \ge 1.$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac1{1-(1)}=1^0+1^1+1^2+\dots?$$

It makes no sense whatsoever for $z=1$.

For $z=2$:

$$-1=\frac1{1-(2)}=1+2+4+8+16+\dots\to\infty?$$

$$\implies-1=\infty??$$

In fact, for any $|z|\ge1$, this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: One more question. $e^z=e \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {(z-1)^n}{n!}$  $|z-1|< \infty$, so why in this case $|z-1|$ can be any value ? because $\lim_{n ->\infty}\frac{(z-1)^n}{n!}$ is always 0 no matter what?

Comment: @Daniel Since after the first $2z$ terms, note that almost every term $\frac{(z-1)^n}{n!}\approx0$, you can easily see that for any positive $z$ it will converge.  Then note for any negative $z$, it converges absolutely.  If you wish for more insight, try Stirling's approximation, it may help explain.

Comment: For example if I have the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nz^{4n+1}}{3^{2n+2}}$, how do I determine the right upper and lower bound for $|z|$?

Comment: @Daniel For that one, use the comparison test to the example problem you originally gave.

Comment: The comparison test? umm. I am just going to make another thread

Comment: @Daniel if $\sum x^n$, then by the comparison test, $\sum x^{n+1}$ also converges, and so does $\sum x^{n-1}$.  Basically, compare a hard summation to a similar but much simpler summation to test for convergence.

Answer (score 1):

If series converges for some $z_0 \geq 1$, then $\lim _{z \to z_0} z^n=0$ It is impossible.

Comment: By the term test, in case its not so clear.